# Understanding simple numerical calculation

Tags: numerics, number-representation

I am trying to understand why `N[0.1]//FullForm` returns `0.1'` (A).
Indeed, $0.1$ in base two is $0.000110011001100110011...$. If I truncate this number to the first 52 digits and convert it back to base ten, I get:

```
Table[1/2^(4*i) + 1/2^(4*i + 1), {i, 1, 12}] // Total // FullForm // N
(* 0.09999999999999964` denoted by (B) *)
```

which is different from the obtained result (A).

However, computing the following operation returns the expected result (B)!

```
N[10.1 - 10)] // FullForm
(* 0.09999999999999964` *)
```

So, what is the difference between the `N[0.1] // FullForm` and `N[10.1 - 10] // FullForm` and why does only the second one return (B)?

Comment: I think this question boils down to the difference between e.g. `N[0.1]` and `N[1.1 - 1]`. The division itself is not the source of the problem.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Right, edited.

Comment: How did you calculate the binary representation? There is no such thing as a dot in binary formats. The binary representation of floating point numbers is via significant and exponent. For 0.1 it is 1x10^-1, that is, Both significant (1) and exponent (-1) are exactly represented in a 64 bit float.

Comment: @Felix Consider $1100110011...11\times 2^{-48}$ if you prefer (and note that `BaseForm[0.1, 2]` returns `"0.00011001100110011001101"` in MMA ;)).

Comment: The numbers are not represented as a x 2^b. It's a x 10^b.

Comment: `N[.1]` , `N[1.1-1]` , `N[10.1-10.]` , `N[1.1-1.]` all give `0.1` for me..is there some version issue going on?

Comment: ah.. you can also do `N[ 1.1 - 1. ] // FullForm` to see the issue. (You might want to put such into the question. )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Introduction

This seems to be a question more about [IEEE 754 binary64 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) than about *Mathematica* per se.

The significand is 53 bits (52 stored, since the leading bit is assumed to be `1` in a normal number). When the input `"0.1"` is converted to a number, presumably, at some point `1.` is divided by `10.` The OP used the term "truncate," but more precisely, the result should be ***rounded*** to the nearest 53-bit floating-point number.

Some tools one can use to explore the binary representation of machine precision numbers are

```
SetPrecision[x, Infinity]
RealDigits[x, 2, 53]
```

`SetPrecision[x, Infinity]` converts the machine real to the exact fraction represented by the floating point number `x`.  `RealDigits[x, 2, 53]` shows the values of the bits. If you replace the `53` with `54` or higher, the last "bits" will be returned as `Indeterminate`.  Below I plot the bits so that a `1` is red, `0` is white, and `Indeterminate` is gray.  The 53-bit limit is indicated with a vertical grid line.

### OP's examples

In the OP's example `Table[]` command, the computed fraction is truncated too soon.  Here is a table showing what is going on.  The first three rows are the OP's table carried out to `12` iterations (as in the OP) up to `14`.  One has to go up to `14` to get all the bits needed to approximate `0.1` to machine precision.  The last three rows show the bits of the machine real `0.1`, the result of `SetPrecision[0.1, Infinity]`, and the exact fraction `1/10`.  One can see that rounding `1/10` results in a carry at the last bit.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> ```
> ClearAll[tenth, mantissaplot, frexp];
> tenth[n_] := Table[1/2^(4*i) + 1/2^(4*i + 1), {i, 1, n}] // Total;
> mantissaplot[{digits_, exp_}, ref_: 0.1] := {ArrayPlot[
>     {digits}, ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, Indeterminate -> Gray},
>     Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black], 
>     ImageSize -> 450, Axes -> {True, False}, 
>     GridLines -> {{exp - Ceiling@Log2[ref], 53}, None}],
>    exp};
> frexp[x_, bits_: 54] := mantissaplot@RealDigits[x, 2, bits];
> TableForm[
>  Join[
>   Table[frexp[tenth[n], 57], {n, 12, 14}],
>   {frexp[0.1, 57],
>    frexp[SetPrecision[0.1, Infinity], 57],
>    frexp[1/10, 57]}
>   ],
>  TableHeadings -> {{12, 13, 14, 0.1, Subscript[0.1, Infinity], 
>     1/10}, {"significand", "exp"}}]
> ```

Now let's take up the OP example `10.1 - 10.`
In the table below, we can see that to store `10.1` the part representing `0.1` is shifted over 7 bits, so that the last 7 bits in `0.1` above are dropped.  When `10.` is subtracted, the result is shifted back, but the 7 bits are already lost. (This what is meant by precision loss due to subtractive cancellation.)

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> ```
> TableForm[{
>   frexp[10.1],
>   frexp[10.1 - 10.],
>   frexp[0.1]
>   },
>  TableHeadings -> {{10.1, HoldForm[10.1 - 10.], 0.1}, {"significand", "exp"}}]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

My original answer is based on the apparently wrong assumption that the numbers are represented by $s\times 10^e$ with significand $s$ and exponent $e$. The correct binary representation is $s\times 2^e$ with $s$ having 52 bits plus one bit for the sign and $e$ being 11 bits long for 64 bit floating point numbers. Therefore, 0.1 is not exactly represented by this format.

**Original answer:**

All your numbers are exactly represented as floating point numbers. There are certain operations that preserve this precision. It seems not changing the exponent is one of them:

```
N[0.2 - 0.1] // FullForm
(* 0.1` *)
```

and only changing the exponent is one of them:

```
N[10/0.1] // FullForm
(* 100.` *)
```

However, changing both in one operation may lead to numerical errors:

```
N[1.1-1.0] // FullForm
(* 0.10000000000000009` *)
```