# Weird things happening when replacing expressions

Tags: numerics, replacement, precision-and-accuracy

I have the following expression:

```
     eqs3=-2.750863054772633*^7*Subscript[x, 18] + 197943.17573209677*Sqrt[1.03*^7 - 1.*Subscript[x, 19]] + 
 2.750863054772633*^7*Subscript[x, 19] + 
 (-95931.14816252001 + (1.2622519495068421*^9*
     (-0.0001568174846625767*Sqrt[1.03*^7 - 1.*Subscript[x, 18]] + 0.021793296146996537*
       Subscript[x, 18] + 0.000076*Sqrt[1.03*^7 + Subscript[x, 18]] - 
      0.021793296146996537*Subscript[x, 19]))/Sqrt[1.03*^7 + Subscript[x, 18]])*
  Sqrt[1.03*^7 + Subscript[x, 19]]
```

I'm going to apply several rules, as follows.

```
eqs3 /. 
 Thread[{Subscript[x, 19], Subscript[x, 18]} -> -8673600.700]

(*0*)

eqs3 /. 
 Thread[{Subscript[x, 18], Subscript[x, 19]} -> -8673600.700]

(*0*)

eqs3 /. Subscript[x, 18] -> -8673600.700 /. 
 Subscript[x, 19] -> -8673600.700

(*0*)
```

So far so good, if it wasn't that...

```
eqs3 /. Subscript[x, 19] -> -8673600.700 /. 
 Subscript[x, 18] -> -8673600.700

(*0.00842667*)
```

Why is so??? This is very much disappointing.

Comment: With the definition you give, `eqs3[[8]]` does not make much sense?!

Comment: Sorry I'll correct this.

Comment: Exactly as @Mr.Wizard shows, I can also not reproduce your results. (I get the same as Mr.Wizard does)

Comment: I think this is a matter of precision on the coefficients of the expression. When copying the expression some of the coefficients must have been chopped. I'll try and sort this out by putting the bits of code in InputForm. @gwr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are operating in the range of numeric noise for the given computation, similar to [Funny behaviour when plotting a polynomial of high degree and large coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3152/121).  As astutely illustrated by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) in that Q&A setting false accuracy (i.e. `Rationalize`) doesn't produce a meaningful result.  If we instead use arbitrary precision, which tracks precision, we see that your results are all equally bad:

```
eqsTracked = SetPrecision[eqs3, $MachinePrecision];
val = SetPrecision[-8673600.700, $MachinePrecision];

r1 = eqsTracked /. Subscript[x, 18 | 19] -> val
r2 = eqsTracked /. Subscript[x, 18] -> val /. Subscript[x, 19] -> val
r3 = eqsTracked /. Subscript[x, 19] -> val /. Subscript[x, 18] -> val

Precision /@ {r1, r2, r3}
```

> ```
> 0.*10^-1
>
> 0.*10^-1
>
> 0.*10^-1
>
> {0, 0, 0}
> ```

So every result has zero digits of [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html).

Here is another way to look at this.  If we convert every machine precision number to an explicit [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) equivalent of exact arithmetic, using Michael's formula, we find:

```
machineToInterval = 
  c_Real?MachineNumberQ :>
    Interval[ {1 - 2^-53, 1 + 2^-53} * SetPrecision[c, ∞] ];

val = -8673600.700 /. machineToInterval;

eqs3 /. machineToInterval /. Subscript[x, 18 | 19] -> val // N
```

> ```
> Interval[{-0.21192, 0.21192}]
> ```

So at most we can say that your result is somewhere in the interval $[-0.21192, 0.21192]$

Comment: Please note that I have edited my question copying the expression in InputForm.

Comment: Would you please explain further more the functioning og machineToInterval? I'm kind of puzzled. How does it manage to define the interval? What would be the mathematical meaning of this? Thanks for your answer, I have the feeling I'm learning something important.

Comment: @MirkoAveta Assuming I didn't screw it up it should be just as Michael E2 describes in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59612/121).  2^-54 comes from the number of bits used in the binary representation of machine numbers.  See [another answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135646/121) again by Michael E2.

Comment: May ask a further question? I faced this problem when attempting to solve a very complicated system of 20 nonlinear equations. One of the variables after several substitutions turned out to be eqs3. I was wondering, if I could proceed with the intervals, as I'm doing now and what happens when I apply machineToInterval to more variables? How do these intervals act together?

Comment: @MirkoAveta It may be best to post a new Question on that topic.  Not all operators will work with `Interval` but the basic arithmetic ones do, as do a fair number of numeric functions, e.g. `Through[{Min, Max, Floor, Sin, Abs, UnitStep}[Interval[{-3.5, 5}]]]`.

Comment: @MirkoAveta I just realized from Michael's analysis I should have used `2^-53` for the *maximum* error rather than supposed mean error.  I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with numerical precision. Note that the problem does not arise when you work with exact coefficients (e.g. using [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)):

```
eqs3r = Rationalize[ eqs3, 0];

With[ { c = Rationalize[-8673600.700] },
  SameQ[
    (eqs3r /. Subscript[x, 19] -> c /. Subscript[x, 18] -> c)
    ,
    (eqs3r /. Subscript[x, 18] -> c /. Subscript[x, 19] -> c)
  ]
]
```

> True