# question on precision. difference between 2 very close numbers

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I am learning precision and accuracy in Mathematica numerics. I need little help to  try to understand why I am not getting the same result  I expect in the following. I have 2 numbers, each is 50 decimal point and differ by the 50'th decimal point.

So when I take the difference, I expected to get `1/10000....0000` with 50 zeros there.  I did make sure the numbers are entered using `SetPrecision[...,Infinity]`

So I must be doing something wrong. Or not doing something in addition to this. There are so many options related to accuracy and precision in Mathematica, and it can get confusing for me what to set and to what value.  Here is the code

```
r0=SetPrecision[0.12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890,Infinity];
r1=SetPrecision[0.12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567891,Infinity]; 

r1-r0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(I also tried `SetPrecision[r1-r0,Infinity]`, no difference)

The equivalant Maple code is

```
Digits:=100: #for display
r0:=0.12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890:
r1:=0.12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567891:
r1-r0;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
convert(r1-r0,rational,'exact');
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Question is: How can one obtain the same result as shown in Maple output?

I am using 11.1 on windows 7.

Comment: must you use SetPrecision?

Comment: @bobbym well, I was just told to do so here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141604/how-to-get-exact-rationalize-of-a-decimal-number  That is what so confusing about all of this.

Comment: Check this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135636/understanding-simple-numerical-calculation

Comment: @AnjanKumar thanks. But the above is all about floating point stuff. I want to do symbolic stuff. Just like on piece of paper. That is what I am using Mathematica and not Matlab :)  On paper, I should get same result shown by Maple (another computer algebra program). That is why I set precision to infinity. I want exact decimal point calculations, like on paper.

Comment: @Nasser, but Maple gave a floating point answer, which then had to be converted to an exact one.

Comment: @bobbym maple uses decimal point representation internally, not hardward floating point. The numbers are still exact internally as you can see. The actual output of 1*10^-50 vs  fraction is not important, as I can convert from to the another. This is just display issue.  Maple can do hardware floating point if needed. But default is decimal point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want decimal representation:

```
dec = # ~RealDigits~ 10 ~FromDigits~ 10 &;

r0 = 0.12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890;
r1 = 0.12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567891;

dec[r1] - dec[r0]
```

> ```
> 1/100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> ```

Of course the *default* is decimal so this can be written less explicitly as:

```
dec = FromDigits @* RealDigits;
```

Related:

- [Does Mathematica have an equivalent of Python's float.as_integer_ratio?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84234/121)

Comment: There somehow exists an edge case for 17 digits long real numbers, where an implicit conversion to `MachinePrecision` happens that can remove the last digit. For example one has to use something like ``r0 = 0.12345678901234567`17;
r1 = 0.12345678901234568`17;`` instead of `r0 = 0.12345678901234567;
r1 = 0.12345678901234568;` to get `dec[r1] - dec[r0]` not returning `0`.

Comment: @Karsten7 Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to duplicate Maple's answer.

```
r0 = 0.12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890000000000;
r1 = 0.12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567891000000000;

r1 - r0

(*1.00000000*10^-50*)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand why you had to add more zeros there? I'd like to duplicate the answer given the input as is. What is the reason to modify the input and adding arbitrary zeros? And I thought one is supposed to use `SetPrecision` when entering decimals numbers with lots of digits.

Comment: I did not mean to confuse you, I agree with your complaints. The adding of zeroes tells mathematica that the error in the numbers is less. Trailing zeroes are significant when there is a decimal point. You can take a look at your last post where in my answer I used the same trick.