# Unpredictable behavior of numerical error

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision, digits

A comparison of float calculation and exact expression for

```
  NumberForm[0.3^2 - (3/10)^2, 18]
```

gives an exact zero for $0.3$. 
However,

```
R[n_Integer] = n 1./10.;
Rex[n_Integer] = n/10;
Table[R[n]^2 - Rex[n]^2, {n, 1, 5}]
```

gives

```
{1.73472*10^-18, 6.93889*10^-18, 2.77556*10^-17, 2.77556*10^-17, 0.}
```

Thus, here we get

```
0.3^2 - (3/10)^2 = 2.77556*10^-17
```

instead of zero. Why is the ouput different in the Table[] calculation?

Comment: Is your question: why does `0.3^2 - (3/10)^2` return `0.` while `R[3]^2 - Rex[3]^2` returns `2.77556*10^-17`?

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135636/understanding-simple-numerical-calculation

Comment: This could be simplified considerably. It amounts to having done some arithmetic just to get the ".3" in `R[3]`: `In[17]:= {.3, (3*1./10)} // InputForm                                           

Out[17]//InputForm= {0.3, 0.30000000000000004}`